# Webflow HTML Embed and Weglot translation

Tags: webflow

I am using an HTML embed for a newsletter signup form. With Weglot translations, I would like to use a different embed for each translation. Can someone point me to a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it [with this support article](https://support.weglot.com/article/262-how-to-display-some-contents-only-in-a-specific-language).